# Why I got different R2 between the predicted and actual data in test dataset in h2o and caret::R2()?

Tags: r, h2o

I would like to get R2 between the predicted  and actual data in test dataset, why the result from h2o.performance(m,  test) is different from caret::R2() or a 'lm' model?

'h2o.performance(m,  test)' is  0.733401, and 'caret::R2(p,  a)' is 0.7577784
 summary(lmm)$r.squared is the same as 'caret::R2(p,  a)'

Example code:

```
library(h2o)

h <- h2o.init()
data <- as.h2o(iris)
part <- h2o.splitFrame(data, 0.7, seed = 123)
train <- part[[1]]
test <- part[[2]]

m <- h2o.glm(x=2:5,y=1,train, nfolds = 10, seed = 123)

summary(m)
predictions <- h2o.predict(m, test)

p <- as.data.frame(predictions)
a <- as.data.frame(test[1])
caret::R2(p,  a)
# 0.7577784
h2o.performance(m,  test)
# the R^2 is 0.733401
df <- data.frame(p=p, a=a)
lmm <- lm(predict ~ Sepal.Length, data =df)
summary(lmm)$r.squared
# the r.squared is 0.7577784
```

Comment: h2o perfromance will help you https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.20.0.8/topics/h2o.performance

Answer (score 1):

You can get training metrics as follows:

```
m <- h2o.glm(x=2:5,y=1,train,validation_frame = test)


  #We would ideally use a validation set. 

h2o.performance(m,test)
m@model$training_metrics
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like to get the R2 for test

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: when I use h2o.performance(m, newdata = test), why the result is different from `caret::R2(as.data.frame(predictions), as.data.frame(test[1])) `

Comment: Did you `set seed`? in both models? The same seed?

Comment: I would think a model built in `caret` would give different results fcompared to that in `h2o`

Comment: That makes the question more suitable for statsexchange. For instance look at this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13869/compare-r-squared-from-two-different-random-forest-models and this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230913/how-caret-calculates-r-squared

Comment: I don't think so. when I use 'df <- data.frame(p=p, a=a)'
'lmm <- lm(predict ~ Sepal.Length, data =df)'
'summary(lmm)$r.squared', the result is same as 'caret::R2()'

Comment: It's a `seed` problem. I don't get the same `R2` as that stated in your question.